# Join with 3 tables related

Tags: mysql, sql, join, union

I need help with a sql query using 3 tables.

The tables are:

ta_taxista:

id,nombre_taxista,

ta_usuario:

id,nombre_usuario

ta_carrera:

id_carrera,ta_taxista_id_taxista,ta_usuario_id_usuario, direccion_origen,direccion_destino estado,fecha.

I need show: nombre_taxista, nombre_usuario, direccion_origen,direccion_destino, fecha filtered by estado.

Can you helpme,

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Freehanding it, but something like;

```
SELECT nombre_taxista, nombre_usuario, direccion_origen,direccion_destino, fecha
FROM ta_carrera
JOIN ta_taxista ON ta_taxista.id = ta_taxista_id_taxista
JOIN ta_usuario ON ta_usuario.id = ta_usuario_id_usuario
WHERE estado...
```

This is really basic join syntax, probably something you could easily read up on.

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.nombre_taxista, t2.nombre_usuario,t3.direccion_origen, t3.direccion_destino from ta_taxista t1, ta_usuario t2, ta_carrera t3 where t1.id=t2.id and t1.id=t3.ta_taxista_id_taxista and t2.id=t3.ta_usuario_id_usuario order by t3.estado
```

Try the above query. Forgive me for any spelling mistakes (if any)